# How to run complex imagemagick command with Carrierwave and Minimagick?

Tags: imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I have a command that creates a watermark on a image, how to put this command on a process with minimagick?

```
convert -size 120x80 xc:none -fill "rgba(20,20,20,0.2)" -gravity NorthWest -draw "text 10,10 'Copyright'" -gravity SouthEast -draw "text 5,15 'Copyright'" miff:- | composite -tile - original.jpg watermarked.jpg
```

Uploader

```
process :watermark
def watermark
   ???
end
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a `|` after `miff:-`

Comment: Thanks. But I dont know how to put this command on carrierwave with minimagick. Any Idea?